# Rotating UIImage give blank UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I Want to rotate UIImage in 90 degrees with this method :

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}
UIImage* rotate(UIImage* src, UIImageOrientation orientation)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(-90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    }

    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
```

the problem is that it give me a blank UIImage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code :-

```
UIImage *PortraitImage;
PortraitImage  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: currentImage.CGImage
                                                    scale: 1.0
                                              orientation: UIImageOrientationLeft];
```

if you want to rotate UIImage at some particular angle then you can use CIIFilter to rotate at whatever angle you want but that is possible in IOS 5.0

```
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"old-country-rain.jpg"]];
CIFilter *RotateFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIStraightenFilter"];
[RotateFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.04667f]  forKey:@"inputAngle"];
[RotateFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
CIImage *displayImage = RotateFilter.outputImage;
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:displayImage];
```

Comment: I find the CIImage extents do not change after rotation. Any recommendations? displayImage.extents for my image is 640 x 480. After rotation the displayImage.extents are still 640 x 480.